# Open source framework for ESP8266 to work with Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant

Tags: mqtt, alexa, esp8266, google-home, sonoff

I'm working on a multi channel sonoff device with ESP8266.

I want it to be able to support popular iot home control platforms such as Amazon Alexa, Google home... It must have a button and share temporary wifi AP for initial setup

Also, I want develop a custom mobile application for it.

So I'm looking for a good framework to support all these features.

I saw some project's on Github (Tasmota , ESPHome...) but I don't see a support for Alexa, Google or other home control platforms in their documentation

Answer (score 4):

Given the basic requirements, you might want to try out mongoose OS. It's fast to setup, support for Amazon Alexa, Google home etc. Lots of documentation available.

The only thing I'm not sure of "out of the box" is your act as an AP requirement for setup.

Mongoose OS is **Open Source** and dual-licensed: Mongoose OS Community Edition - Apache License Version 2.0. ~wikipedia

The official website for the "IoT Operating System - Mongoose OS" can be found here: https://mongoose-os.com/

Comment: Mongoose OS looks interesting. I'm hopeful you can confirm something; It looks like if I want to use it on my devices without using their mDash cloud service I have to buy a per device license. The license cost looks like it's pretty cheap per device, but is that a one time purchase?